# I'd like to rename the 'Weight' section in WooCommerce, but there doesn't seem to be an API call for it. How can this be done?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, dom, woocommerce

I'm pretty new to web development and have mostly been doing minor PHP edits on WordPress / WooCommerce, but my client would like me to edit the name of the 'Weight' tab as shown in the image below.

[WooCommerce Website Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfylx.png)

I have not yet been able to figure it out using the WooCommerce API since I do not think that function is included, and I have the feeling I will have to do some DOM using PHP but I have no experience doing that.

Could somebody help to point me in the right direction? It would be greatly appreciated.

Additional Link:

- https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html

Comment: and what name you suppose to use instead of WEIGHT

Comment: this is in your descriptions of products or are you using it as a product attribute

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use woo commerce hooks to change weight spellings or you can edit woo commerce plugin

File path:- plugins-woocommerce-templates

But if you edits woocommerce templates directly when you update plugins then your custom works does not any more.

Comment: Thanks! This managed to resolve my issue :) I also do have modifications to my functions.php file which I need to modify after each WooCommerce update, but it is not too much trouble to go back and edit. For anybody else having this issue, the full patch was /plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-attributes.php

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to this to use the WooCommerce language file and add translations for 'Weight', 'Weight in decimal form', and 'Weight unit'.

This approach has the advantage of not needing to modify WooCommerce source files.